# Change CSS class with if/else on droppable

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Solution: I changed
        $(this).removeClass('inactivetile').addClass('incorrecttile');

to

     ui.draggable.removeClass('inactivetile').addClass('incorrecttile');

doi

I've tried a few different things here, but I'm coming up empty. 
Basically I want to have a droppable that will check to see what id is dropped on it and change the css accordingly. For example sake let's say I have two draggables: `#drag1` and `#drag2` and one droppable: `#drop1`. 
When #drag1 is dropped on `#drop1` the css class changes from .droptile to `.correcttile` - if `#drag2` is dropped, then the css class changes from `.droptile` to `.incorrecttile.` Sounds simple enough, but I can't seem to get past this:

```
  $('#drop1').droppable({
  hoverClass: 'hovered'});

  $('#drop1').on('drop', function (event, ui) {

  var itemid = $(ui.draggable).attr('id'); //tried this and then called it in the else statement with no luck

      if ($(ui.draggable).attr('id') == 'drop1') {
          ui.draggable.position({ of: $(this) });
          $('#drop1').removeClass('droptile').addClass('correcttile')
      }
      else {
          ui.draggable.position({ of: $(this) });
          $(this).removeClass('droptile').addClass('incorrecttile');
      }

  });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In the if condition you are using `drop1` instead of `drag1`

```
$('#drop1').on('drop', function (event, ui) {

    var dragId = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');

    ui.draggable.position({
        of: $(this)
    });

    $(this).removeClass('droptile').addClass(dragId == 'drag1' ? 'correcttile' : incorrecttile)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0znm8ghw/)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I changed
$(this).removeClass('inactivetile').addClass('incorrecttile'); 
to 
ui.draggable.removeClass('inactivetile').addClass('incorrecttile'); 
doi

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable1" ).draggable();
    $( "#draggable2" ).draggable();

    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
          if( ui.draggable.attr('id') == 'draggable1' ){
              $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" ).find( "p" ).html("Dropped!" );
          }
      }
    });
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ygk4k7gc/ full example